# I cannot hit my website, hosted in IIS 8 on internal network via mobile device using domain name

Tags: iis, networking, dns, web, ip

I am able to access my website via the domain name outside of the network.

On the internal network I am able to access the site via "localhost/websiteName/", "internalIP/websiteName", and "computerName/websiteName", but I am unable to hit either "http://example.com" or "http://www.example.com".

I was able to get it to work on a computer by adding the ip and website to the hosts file, but I am still unable to access the website using the domain via mobile devices on the internal WiFi.

I completely disabled the firewall, so I know that that is not the problem.

I have bindings set up for www and without www with all IP Adresses unassigned.

I did try adding a binding for both www and not, using the internal and external IP addresses, both IPv4 and IPv6.

I am running this on http without any certificates.

I have a cname record for www

My @ record is pointing to my external, static IP

The website is set up separately from the default website and it is not a virtual directory.

I am using Comcast Business with their Cisco DPC3939B router.

This is initial setup of the website, and it is not an issue that just started after having worked previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. All I did was add an @ record to the DNS to resolve the website to the internal IP. Here is a really great reference for accessing websites on a Local Network: [devside.net](http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/accessing-websites-on-a-local-network-lan-web-server)